# Como sumar o restar valores de campos en JasperReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft

Estoy haciendo un reporte en el que ocupo obtener la suma o resta de valores en un campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ocupo sumar las cantidades de los campos señalados en la imagen, el problema es que esos campos los muestro de la siguiente forma:

```
$F{Cuenta} == 1 ? ($F{ValorM}) :
$F{Cuenta} == 0 ? ($F{ValorM}) : ""
```

La variable cuenta la uso para diferenciar si es una entrada o salida del almacén.
Pero no he encontrado una forma para sumar o restar el valor de estos campos en el de saldo.

Comment: Suponiendo que las cantidades siempre son positivas; multiplica cada cantidad por `1` o por `-1` según la cuenta, y suma ambos resultados. Si son valores númericos no uses cadena vacía en operadores ternarios, puede ser mas conveniente regresar `null` y usar *Blank When Null*. Puedes meter la lógica de la cuenta en una variable.